# Android set image as wallpaper

Tags: android, image, background, imageview, wallpaper

Please show me an example code on how to set image as wallpaper using Android WallpaperManager. I have shortened and edited my question. Hopefully you guys could understand my question. I will show some attempts I have made.

HomeActivity.class

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

    String[] imageUrls;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_home);
        ArrayList<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL url_link = new URL("http://mywebsite.net/web/thumb.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url_link.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("list");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element)node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("thumb_url");
                Element nameElement = (Element)nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

                url.add(nameList.item(0).getNodeValue());
            }
            imageUrls = (String[]) url.toArray(new String[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }
    public void onImageGridClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onImagePagerClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

ImagePagerActivity.class

```
package com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader;


import java.io.IOException;


import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;


public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ViewPager pager;

    private DisplayImageOptions options;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
        int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACT)
            .build();

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
        pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);
    }

    public void setWallpaper() {

        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
         = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
         myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.pager); // nothing happened 
        } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_clear_memory_cache:
                imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
                return true;
            case R.id.item_clear_disc_cache:
                setWallpaper();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        imageLoader.stop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private String[] images;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
            this.images = images;
            inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View container) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
            final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, null);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

            imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                public void onLoadingStarted() {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
                }

                public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImagePagerActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
                    imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                    anim.start();
                }

                public void onLoadingCancelled() {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            });

            ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View container) {
        }
    }

}
```

1st Attempt (My `pagerPosition` is giving error "pagerPosition cannot be resolved to a variable")

```
public void setWallpaper(){
             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), pagerPosition);
    try {
         ImagePagerActivity.this.setWallpaper(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Gallery Example", "Image setted.");
            }
```

2nd Attempt (My pagerPosition is giving error "pagerPosition cannot be resolved to a variable")

```
public void setWallpaper() {

        try {
            File file = new File("/sdcard/sampleimage");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), pagerPosition);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(file));
            Context context = this.getBaseContext();
            context.setWallpaper(bitmap);            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper has been set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         
    }

@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.set_wallpaper:
                    setWallpaper();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

3rd Attempt (My setResource(R.id.pager) is not getting the image from the viewpager.

```
public void setWallpaper() {

        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
         = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
         myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.id.pager);
        } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Conclusion

If i put the below codes above my `onCreate` my whole project will not run.

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
        final int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);
```

Comment: can you post whole code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below code in ImagePagerActivity, i tested below code and it is working.

```
    // fetch bitmap from view
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view
            .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        // if we unable to get background drawable then we will set white color as wallpaper
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}

public void setWall(int i) {
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        // below line of code will set your current visible pager item to wallpaper
        // first we have to fetch bitmap from visible view and then we can pass it to wallpaper
        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(getBitmapFromView(pager.getChildAt(1)));

        // below line of code will set input stream data directly to wallpaper
        // myWallpaperManager.setStream(InputStream Data);

        // below line of code will set any image which is in the drawable folder 
        // myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.icon);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It will set current visible pager's item view(if it is progress wheel or image).

Comment: @rajpara I didnt work for me. can you explain what do you pass in i of setWall(int i) ? Thanks

Comment: @rajpara, I have asked a similar [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414798/set-image-wallaper-of-viewpager-in-universal-image-loader-uil), could give me a hand pls, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with your setbackground method...

```
String imagePath = ""; // YOUR PATH HERE
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap bitmapToUse = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
b.recycle();

if(!("").equals(imagePath)){
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmapToUse);
}
```

That should set your file to your wallpaper no problem.

Can you be more specific on what you need for the "saveImage()"? Where are you trying to save from? Is it local storage? Or a website? More details please.

[Edit]
Updated code for clarity

[Edit 2]
To save images from a URL...

```
File imageFile = new File("image.png"); // This is location AND file name, all i put here was the filename
URL url = new URL("http://www.whatever.com/image.png");

                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                            .getInputStream());

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

[Edit 3]

The 'parent' is either your parent view (generally the view for the current activity). There are other ways to set this, the parent.width/height is how you're going to define how large the wallpaper image needs to be.

Comment: I've put in the codes you have suggested, my image path is imageUrls. How do set it into my codes? and I'm having error on the parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight() . "parent cannot be resolved" . I would like to download those images into my local SD. Please guide me on this Ryan . Thanks.

Comment: Dear Ryan, Thanks for your answer. Could you please show me how do I link my Imagepath to setbackground() ?

Comment: The 'imagePath' variable in my first function (for setWallpaper) should have the same location as 'imageFile', the variable for retrieving the image from the URL. Basically you're going to download and save an image to the device from a url. Lets say www.whatever.com/image.png gets saved to /sdcard/image.png. You would use that save location for both imageFile and imagePath. HOWEVER, if you're using the SDCard as the save place, let me know now so you don't run into more problems.

Comment: I've edited my codes, could you please take a look.The problem is I dont know how to set my Image location into my setbackground() method. PLease help me. Thanks

Comment: You're declaring "pagerPosition" as a local variable inside of your onCreate method... which is why it doesn't get recognized later. Move it outside of the onCreate method and that should fix that issue